# Need advice with the removal of the soleplate

Tags: walls, framing, structural

WARNING: I know nothing about building houses. So feel free to teach me a thing or two.

We are removing the bathroom so that will an open space as part of the living room.

In red:

-> Sole plate within the red area will be removed

-> The stud on top of the Sole plate will also be removed

In green:

-> Sole plate will stay

-> header will be added

Is that okay if he removes that sole plate and stud marked in red to have an entrance from the living room area to the bathroom?

More images -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9vVb.jpg

More images + video -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6jVa.jpg

[image]

Comment: Beams are never vertical. If anything, it's a post, or just a stud. I don't know what "added to the furthest point" means. If the red stud is gone the sole plate serves no purpose.

Comment: I'm just confused. What's the horizontal green box up high? Are you putting in a header? Please have a look at a [framing terms list](https://www.zeelandlumber.com/basic-house-framing-terms-you-need-to-know/) so we can speak the same language.

Comment: Why are you only removing some of the wall and leaving a post if you want it to be open? Does that mean you have **determined** that  it is a load bearing wall? What are the reasons for your decisions? We need more and correct information.

Comment: @isherwood I have used the wrong word sorry, I meant a header and not a beam. I edited the question, kindly ckeck.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I am removing some of it and keeping the rest to make an entrance from the living room area to the bathroom area. I updated the question, I hope it makes more sense

Comment: Are you removing the red marked stud to install a door to the bathroom, or are you completely removing the bathroom wall and all the bathroom furniture, or something else? It makes no sense to me to remove the bathroom but leave the 2 studs sitting on the "green" section of sole plate, so I'm really baffled...

Answer (score 2):

The strategy of adding a header to replace one or more studs is appropriate, with one caveat: The header must be adequate to carry the load of the floor above as well as any roof that's bearing at that point, if those currently rest on that wall. The header must rest on "trimmer" studs, which aren't shown in your diagram, whether it's load-bearing or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you'll want to do (making allowances for your particular dimensions and geometry):

[image: Rough Door Opening]

...and it's just my (unsolicited) two cents, but you might consider putting the door closer to the corner (at the left in your photo, where the ladder is) so that people wouldn't walk into the bathroom and directly into the toilet.

(I don't seem to be able to find the source for this diagram, I found it on Pinterest, but the link associated with it goes to a porn site...)

Comment: +1 for the "move the door so you don't run into the toilet" note, and +100 for _not_ including the link to the pron site.